# cannot name object from prop value

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass an object key value to a component through a props. When I destructure the value, the function doesn't recognize it as a variable. How can is use the prop value in this function?

```
 const TemplateInput = ({compID, templateObj, setTemplateObj }) => {


   const handleUpdateTitle = (event) => {

     setTemplateObj({
       ...templateObj,
       compID: { templateTitle: event.target.value, templateType: "" },
     });

     console.log(templateObj);
   };

   return (
<>
  <div className="create-template-item">
    <InputGroup className="mb-3" onChange={handleUpdateTitle}>
      <DropdownButton
        as={InputGroup.Prepend}
        variant="outline-secondary"
        title="placeholder for now"
        id="input-group-dropdown-1"
        variant="info"
      >
        <Dropdown.Item>Current date and time</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Divider />
        <Dropdown.Item>Remove Input</Dropdown.Item>
      </DropdownButton>
      <FormControl
        placeholder="Input Title"
        aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
      />
    </InputGroup>
  </div>
</>
   );
 };
```

Comment: Can you tell us 1) where the error is 2) what you want as output 3) what is the current wrong output?

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of details. Good news is I found the solution. The issue was compID in the setTemplateObj function was not recognized as a variable, it would just say compID in the updated object. I had to add square brackets to [compID] to all it to be recognized